# Obteniendo estado 404 con getResponseCode() ¿fallo en la conexión?

Tags: php, apache2

mi problema consiste en que debugueando mi aplicación en android studio he podido observar que al ejecutar la linea **conn.getErrorStream()** me salta una excepción: **ConnectException ECONNREFUSED**.

Estoy ejecutando mi aplicación sobre un **servidor apache2**, tengo los servicios de apache y mysql iniciados y no estoy seguro si me he saltado algún paso a la hora de configurar el servidor adecuadamente para que funcione la conexión, ya que obviamente ahora no lo está haciendo.

EDIT: Al ejecutar la linea:

int status = con.getResponseCode();

me devuelve el estado 404.

Gracias por adelantado, un saludo.

Comment: Hola.. La conexión ah funcionado anteriormente?

Comment: Hola, al final el error se debía a que no estaba configurando correctamente el archivo php para conectarme al servidor, ya que al tener en el mismo servidor los archivos PHP y la base de datos MySQL debía indicar 'localhost' en el host al que conectarme, y no la dirección del servidor.